# What is a correspondent bank?

Tags: united-states, india, international-transfer, inr-indian-rupee

I want to transfer $500 to my son in the USA. I'm using the online Internet facilty of ICICI bank, Hyderabad through the "money2 world" option.
In spite of my filling all the details like the account number, swift code, routing number, the address of the Bank of America in Atlanta of the beneficiary, the transaction is being rejected with the reason that the
corresponding bank details is not correct.

What is a correspondent bank? Are the details different from the bank details of the beneficiary account in US, in this case the Bank of America in Atlanta?

Comment: Too broad and unclear. Also most likely scam spam.

Comment: I was thinking the same.  Clever to use a small sum.

Answer (score 4):

Your son needs to go to his Bank of America branch in Atlanta and get the  *exact* address of the BOA branch that the SWIFT code is assigned to; it is not necessarily the branch where he banks at, and it might even not be in Atlanta.

A correspondent bank is a bank that small banks use to handle their international bank transactions, e.g. a rupee bank draft that I get
from my (small-town) US bank is drawn on a big bank based in New York,
and international wire transfers *in* to my account actually get 
sent to this big bank
and the money comes via ACH transfer (internal US mechanism for
electronic transfer of funds) to my account.

Comment: My question is We already have all the details of the beneficiary bank....but still the correspondent bank details are being asked...is these two are different?where to get the correspondent bank details?

Comment: Did you not understand the very first sentence of my answer? **Your son** needs to go to **his BOA branch** and talk to a **bank officer**, not a _teller_, to get the information about the corespondent bank, if any. Maybe the Correspondent bank is a BOA branch (or Headquarters) in New York City or Los Angeles, maybe it is a different BOA branch in Atlanta itself, but if your son wants to get that $500, he needs to hustle a bit; nobody here can help you get the information that you need.

Comment: The SWIFT network simply handles the messaging about transfers between banks, but the actual *transactions* for moving the money happen between the correspondent banks.

Answer (score 1):

The correspondent bank would be the intermediary bank(s) typically unknown to most consumers. Correspondence relationships are agreements between banks to facilitate money movements.

In your scenario, I believe that the information that you entered is incorrect or that your son would have to give you the routing number for international wires. Large banks often use multiple routing numbers and the one on your son's checks may not be the correct one.

https://www.bankofamerica.com/deposits/manage/faq-routing-numbers.go

How do I find my ABA routing number?

You can find the correct routing number for the type of transaction you want to make by choosing the state in which your account was opened in the dropdown menu below.

State:Georgia

Paper (ex. Ordering Checks):
061000052

Electronic payment (for example, direct deposit, automatic payments & ACH transfers):
061000052

Wire Transfer:
026009593

Hope this helps !